# C (BEGINNER ) - Writing a 2D array into a file

Tags: c, file, matrix, fwrite, fclose

Hello i would like to store a matrix into a file here's the code I made

```
void fichier_print(grid_t grille, int n){
  int i,j;
  FILE *f_solution;
  f_solution=fopen("solution.txt","wb");
  if( f_solution == NULL )
  {
     printf("Le fichier est corronpu");
     exit(1);
  }
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
      fprintf(f_solution,"%c\n",grille.data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("|\n");
  }
  printf("\n");

  fclose(f_solution);

}
```

Here **grille.data is the matrix that i want to save in a file** .

**The thing is that when i run the code nothing appears no .txt**
( I made sure that I was in the correct directory before saying this ) .

Is there anyone with a clue ? Thanks

Comment: You did not check to see if the file opened successfully.  If it fails you should dump the OS error.

Comment: What is `grid_t ` ?

Comment: Hello I re-edited my code ( I am a beginner ) , so i add if( f_solution == NULL ) , but still nothing happens

Comment: grid_t is a structure i defined

Comment: @MarouaneSharry well yes it's pretty clear that it is some structure, but __what__ is that structure? Depending on how the structure is defined, the code you show may make sense or not. [Edit] your question.

Comment: If your code does not display `Le fichier est corrompu` this either means: 1. you never call `fichier_print`, or 2. the file "solution.txt" is in another directory than the one you think. It depends on your environnment, your OS, your IDE and posibly a few other things.

Comment: @Jabberwocky so in  grid_t i have **data** which is a unsigned char ** I used to create a matrix and int **size** giving the size of the matrix .

Comment: @MarouaneSharry don't describe your code, but show it in the question. Make sure you _actually_ call `fichier_print`, by putting something like `printf("fichier_print called\n");` at the beginning of `fichier_print `, or by using your debugger.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am so dumb i forgot to call the function still learning thanks !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found out himself that he didn't even call the function, sigh.

Comment: I'm a beginner ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simplified guess on your structure (not looking at your comments). Assuming that your `data` structure is correctly initilized, then it should print correctly.

But since on your end there is a problems getting the file you want, my guess is that `grille` content (or in combination with `n`) the data is not properly initialized.

E.g. (the simplified version)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct grid {
    char data[10][10];
};
typedef struct grid grid_t;

void fichier_print(grid_t grille, int n) {
    FILE *f_solution = fopen("solution.txt", "wb");
    if (f_solution == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        printf("Le fichier est corronpu");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) fprintf(f_solution, "%c\n", grille.data[i][j]);
        printf("|\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f_solution);
}

int main(void) {
    grid_t g;
    memset(&g, 'x', sizeof g);
    fichier_print(g, 10);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `perror` would also help in clarifying what (might) be wrong when opening/creating a file.

Comment: OP didn't even call the function, so your answer is somewhat pointless...

Comment: :-) but not completely.